# Apache LoadModule - why are there multiple calls at start-up?

Tags: apache, apache-modules

I am working on using an Apache websocket module on Windows 7. I have used the code kindly provided by "Disconnect" on https://github.com/disconnect/apache-websocket and successfully compiled it to run on Windows 7, following guidance from http://www.calazan.com/how-to-compile-and-build-apache-modules-on-windows-using-visual-studio/. I have an associated plugin called "ws_switch_plugin" that is called from the websocket module in an identical way to that which Disconnect's "echo" plugin example is used.

I am running Apache 2.4.7 within a Xampp 1.8.3 installation. I have configured the httpd.conf file according to the advice from Disconnect.

The strange situation I see is that when Apache starts up, it seems to load the websocket module four times and calls the plugin's "init" function each time. During start-up, two instances of the plugin are immediately destroyed, but two remain open. From further debug based on the handles to the plugins, only the last plugin that is created seems to be used. When Apache is stopped, both outstanding plugins are destroyed.

Below is a listing from a debug file where the function names from the disconnect websocket module are listed as they are called from Apache. When Apache is started, it shows four groups of function calls corresponding to the four apparent loads of the websocket module. Finally, when Apache is stopped, it shows the two instances of the plugins being destroyed.

Can anyone explain why this is happening please? I would like to have the understanding and ideally learn if there is a way to make Apache load the module only once.

```
(WHEN STARTING APACHE ...)

mod_websocket_register_hooks
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path NULL
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path /ws_switch_plugin
    mod_websocket_create_dir_config apr_pcalloc OK
mod_websocket_conf_handler
plugin ws_switch_plugin_init
mod_websocket_conf_handler plugin handle 0079B2F0
mod_websocket_conf_handler response OK
mod_websocket_cleanup_config
DESTROY plugin


mod_websocket_register_hooks
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path NULL
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path /ws_switch_plugin
    mod_websocket_create_dir_config apr_pcalloc OK
mod_websocket_conf_handler
plugin ws_switch_plugin_init
mod_websocket_conf_handler plugin handle 007A30C8
mod_websocket_conf_handler response OK


mod_websocket_register_hooks
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path NULL
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path /ws_switch_plugin
    mod_websocket_create_dir_config apr_pcalloc OK
mod_websocket_conf_handler
plugin ws_switch_plugin_init
mod_websocket_conf_handler plugin handle 00410278
mod_websocket_conf_handler response OK
mod_websocket_cleanup_config
DESTROY plugin


mod_websocket_register_hooks
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path NULL
mod_websocket_create_dir_config path /ws_switch_plugin
    mod_websocket_create_dir_config apr_pcalloc OK
mod_websocket_conf_handler
plugin ws_switch_plugin_init
mod_websocket_conf_handler plugin handle 00418050
mod_websocket_conf_handler response OK


(WHEN STOPPING APACHE ...)

mod_websocket_cleanup_config
DESTROY plugin
mod_websocket_cleanup_config
DESTROY plugin
```

Comment: Well, apache uses children processes or threads to server individual requests. The module has to be loaded into each of these children to be used. You can configure the number of children initially started, kept alive and kept ready, but you cannot disable that feature without crippling the http server. At least not for normal/typical usage scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, arkascha, for your insight here. I had a background concern that the behaviour I had seen was incorrect, but not surprisingly, your comment suggests that it is reasonable. For my education, I tried to find the way of configuring the number of children started, kept alive and ready, which seems to require the mpm_prefork_module to be loaded and configured. However, my installation of Apache 2.4 via Xampp 1.8.3 does not include this module.

Comment: So which worker module _does_ it use? It _must_ use one such module. Others have similar options, though they obviously do not control processes but other things, depending on the strategy implemented by the module.

Comment: Thank you again, arkascha and apologies for the delay in my response here! Your question has prompted me to learn a little more about Apache on Windows and, by provoking the httpd.exe from the command line with "httpd -l", I see that the compiled-in mpm_winnt module is being used. I have found the httpd-mpm.conf file under the "extra" directory within the Apache conf directory. This has configuration for 150 ThreadsPerChild. For experiment, I put this to 1, but my observations in the original post above remained. I have no further understanding at this point.